# Анимация постепенного появления svg в виде движения стрелки часов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, svg, анимация

Я использую изображение SVG в своем HTML, и я хочу, чтобы оно появилось. Пока здесь ничего сложного.

Но что мне нужно, так это то, чтобы  изображение было не везде одинаковое.

Я хочу, чтобы постепенный переход начинался сверху, затем следовал по виртуальному кругу вокруг изображения, пока круг не будет завершен.

Чтобы возобновить что-то вроде перехода часов на [powerpoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozsOycXPOLs)

Я пытаюсь использовать радиальный градиент, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634023/add-circular-fading-opacity-vignette-effect-to-images-in-css)

Но я не нахожу никакого другого способа, кроме прогрессивного круга из центра или в центр. Кроме того, я использую фон, и изображение SVG имеет некоторую прозрачность, поэтому градиент не работает.

Вот код, который у меня есть на самом деле, я знаю, что его немного, но я не нахожу никакого направления, на которое я могу взглянуть, чтобы получить желаемый результат:

```js
var isAnimProgressing = false;
$("#button1").click(function() {
  var opa = "0";
  if(!isAnimProgressing) {
    isAnimProgressing = true;
    if($(".test").css("opacity") == "1") {
      opa = "0";
    } else {
      opa = "1";
    }
    $(".test").animate({opacity: opa}, 2000, "linear", function() {
        isAnimProgressing = false;
    });
   }
});

$("#button2").click(function() {
  if($(".test").hasClass("done")) {
    $(".test").removeClass("done");
  } else {
    $(".test").addClass("done");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image : url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg);
}

.test {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.test.done {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button1">JS</button> OR
  <button id="button2">CSS</button>
 <div class="test loading">
  <img src='https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg' alt='loading-cat'>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54199494/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете делать что хотите с анимированной маской SVG и получить нужный вам эффект:

```js
$("#button2").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("clocksweep").beginElement();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image : url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button2">SVG</button>
<div class="test loading">
<svg width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174">
  <defs>
    <mask id="reveal" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <path d="M0,0 L0,1,1,1,1,0 Z" fill="black">
        <animate id="clocksweep" attributeName="d" dur="2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze"
          values="M 0.5,0.5 L 0.5,0, 1,0, 1,0.5, 1,1, 0.5,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 1,0, 1,0, 1,0.5, 1,1, 0.5,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 1,0.5, 1,0.5, 1,0.5, 1,1, 0.5,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 0.5,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 0.5,1, 0.5,1, 0.5,1, 0.5,1, 0.5,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0.5,0 Z;
                  M 0.5,0.5 L 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0, 0.5,0 Z"
          keyTimes="0; 0.125; 0.25; 0.375; 0.5; 0.625; 0.75; 0.875; 1"/>
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#reveal)">
    <ellipse fill="#C6C6C6" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
    <path id="bird" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
 c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
 c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
 c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
 c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
 c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
 c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
 c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
 c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
 c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
 c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
 c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
 c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
 z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
 C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Вариант CSS

```js
$("#button2").click(function() {
  document.querySelector("#reveal").classList.add("animate");
});
```

```css
.cow {
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACEUb.jpg);
background-size:cover;

}
#reveal circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 3.15px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
}
#reveal.animate circle {
    animation: clocksweep 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes clocksweep {
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 3.15px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button2">Click me</button>
<div class="cow">
<svg width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" >
  <defs>
    <mask id="reveal" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="0.5" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,1,1)" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
 
  <g mask="url(#reveal)">
  
    <path id="cowboy" fill="#4D2E1E"  d="M247 327c0 20-2 49-4 71 -2 25-6 42-3 69 2 27 10 64 15 98 5 35 7 67 6 90 -1 23-5 35-7 43 -2 8-4 13-2 15s6 1 14 2l0 0c0 1-1 2-2 3 -3 4-10 7-15 9 -5 1-9 1-12 1 -3 0-4 0-5 3 -1 3-2 8-1 12 1 4 5 6 12 7 6 1 15 0 22-1 8-1 14-3 19-5 4-1 6-2 8-2 2 1 3 4 5 5 2 1 5 2 9 2s9-1 12-2c3-1 5-3 6-8 1-4 1-10 1-16 1 0 3 0 4-1 5-2 5-6 2-22 -3-16-9-44-14-70 -5-26-8-51-10-77 -2-26-1-54-1-70 1-16 3-20 6-8 4 12 10 41 17 75 7 34 14 72 17 100 3 28 2 44 1 55s-3 15 0 17c1 0 2 1 4 1 0 1 0 2 0 3 -1 7 0 15 1 20 1 5 2 7 6 8 3 1 8 2 12 2 4 0 7 0 9-2 2-1 3-4 5-5 2-1 4 0 8 2 4 1 11 4 19 5 8 1 16 2 22 1 6-1 10-3 12-7 1-4 0-9-1-12 -1-3-2-3-5-3 -3 0-7 0-12-1 -5-1-12-4-15-9 0-1-1-1-1-2 5 0 8 0 9-2 1-3-3-11-7-27 -4-16-8-41-12-72 -4-30-8-67-10-99s-4-62-8-88c-4-26-9-49-12-69 -2-14-1-26-1-38 3-17 8-37 12-61 1-6 2-13 3-19 1-3 2-5 4-6 2-1 6 0 11 1 6 1 13 4 22 5 9 1 20 0 26-4 6-4 9-12 8-21 -1-9-6-21-11-34 -5-14-10-30-14-38 -3-8-5-8-6-8 -1 0-3 0-4 0 -1-1-2-2-3-5 -1-3-3-8-4-13 -1-5-1-10-4-14 -3-4-8-6-15-9 -1 0-2-1-2-1 5-3 9-8 10-13 2-5 0-10-4-13 -5-3-12-4-19-3 -3 0-5 1-7 2 0 0 0-1 0-1 0-9-2-18-4-25 -2-6-5-9-7-10s-5 2-8 3c-3 1-8 0-13 0s-11-2-15-3 -9-3-13-2c-4 1-7 5-9 10 -2 4-3 10-3 16 -4-1-7-2-10-2 -9-1-15 1-19 5 -4 4-6 10-6 15 1 6 4 12 9 17 6 5 13 10 22 12 1 0 2 0 3 1 0 3 1 6 2 9 0 1 0 3 0 4 0 6 0 12-2 18 -1 3-3 7-5 10 -5-1-10-1-15 0 -7 1-13 3-15 5 -2 2 1 5 1 8 0 1-1 2-1 3 -9 2-16 4-22 6 -5 2-10 4-12 7v0l0 0c-4 4-7 11-12 26 -5 15-11 40-17 63 -5 24-10 47-13 66 -3 19-6 34-8 44 -2 10-4 14-3 16 1 1 2 1 4 1 -2 3-4 5-5 8 -2 3-3 7-3 11 0 1 0 3 0 4l0 0c-2 1-4 0-6-1 -1-1-2-2-2-2s-1 2-2 8c-1 6-1 16-1 30 0 14 0 31-1 40 -1 9-2 9-2 9s2 2 4 2c2 0 5 0 6-2s1-5 1-11 0-14 1-19c1-5 2-7 3-9 1-2 3-5 5-6 2-1 5 0 8-1 3-1 5-4 7-8 2-4 3-9 4-13s1-7 2-10c0 0 0-1 0-1 1 0 1-1 2-1 1-1 2-3 3-4 2-1 6-2 8-3 3-2 5-4 7-7 1-3 1-7 0-9 -1-2-3-3-6-2 -2 1-5 2-8 3 0-2-1-4-1-6l0 0c3 1 5 1 6 1 2-1 2-3 3-9 2-7 5-18 9-30 4-12 10-25 13-41 3-14 4-30 8-37 1 4 1 8 1 11C246 308 246 319 247 327L247 327zM378 170c-4-1-9-1-17-1 -1 0-3 0-4 0 -1-4 0-8-2-8 -2-1-8 1-15 0 0 0-1 0-1 0 0-1 1-5 1-6 3 1 6 0 8 0 3-1 4-3 6-6 2-3 2-3 4-7 2-4 4-8 5-13 2-5 3-12 3-21 0-1 0-2 0-3l0 0c1 0 2 0 3 1 1 3 3 6 5 8 3 4 7 8 9 12 2 4 2 9 4 12 2 3 6 5 8 6 3 2 4 3 5 4 0 1 0 3-1 4s-2 2 0 6c1 3 5 9 9 18 4 9 8 21 7 23 -1 2-8-6-13-12 -5-6-9-9-11-12 -3-2-5-4-8-4C381 170 379 170 378 170z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269727/7394871)@ccprog

Доработана  вёрстка, взят другой svg образ, добавлена картинка фона @Alexandr_TT